# How do I decrease touchpad sensitivity in KDE/Kubuntu on Dell Inspiron?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, touchpad

Keypad sensitivity is perfect when using Gnome on latest stable Ubuntu.  when I change to KDE, however, sensitivity is so high, I can't get anywhere near touchpad without causing changes to cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've installed the `kde-config-touchpad` package. An "Touchpad" configuration module is then available in your "System Settings", aliased "synaptiks". It provides various configuration options for your touchpad, such as multi-touch options, cursor speed, scrolling options, "tapping", etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You adjust the mouse sensitivity. Go to System->Preferences->Mouse. adjust the sensitivity there.
In the Software Center there is an application called Pointing Devices.you can try installing that.
you can install it through the terminal by typing
`sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings`

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called synaptiks. alt-f2 synaptiks